# Why does OpenCPU perform better when returning listed objects?

Tags: php, r, opencpu

I noticed while benchmark testing the OpenCPU API that a function which returns a listed data frame will take considerably less execution time than returning an unlisted data frame of the same size.  It's more noticeable with larger data frames. What is the reason for this difference?  I tested using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and opencpu-server v1.6.

Here are the R functions I used.

```
test1 <- function(n) {
    data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n), z = rnorm(n))
    data
}

test2 <- function(n) {
    data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n), z = rnorm(n))
    list(data)
}
```

And here is the php script I used for testing.

```
<?php
function curl_post($url, $postfields) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$test1sum = 0;
$test2sum = 0;

$postfields = array('n' => 100000);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $time0 = microtime(true);
    $data1 = curl_post('http://localhost/ocpu/library/testpackage/R/test1', $postfields);
    $time1 = microtime(true);
    $data2 = curl_post('http://localhost/ocpu/library/testpackage/R/test2', $postfields);
    $time2 = microtime(true);

    $test1sum += ($time1 - $time0);
    $test2sum += ($time2 - $time1);
}

$test1avg = $test1sum / 10;
$test2avg = $test2sum / 10;

echo $test1avg, '<br>', $test2avg;
?>
```

There wasn't much of a difference for sample sizes of around 10000 or less, here is a benchmark for an *n* of 5000.

```
0.19470419883728
0.15488367080688
```

And here is a benchmark for an *n* of 100000.

```
1.3232709169388
0.23536853790283
```